# What are the numbers in a .NET stack trace on an ASPX error page?

Tags: .net, stack-trace

What are the numbers in a .NET stack trace on an ASPX error page (see picture)? They don't seem to be line numbers as they are too large? How can those numbers help me in determining the line of code that threw the exception?

[image: Stack trace example]

Comment: This was the offset into native code: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/25/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: As this has been marked correct, I might as well edit it to make it so :)

They're offsets within the JITted native code of the method. Unfortunately that means they don't help very much when trying to work out what's going on. See [this blog post](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/25/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx) for a more detailed example.

Comment: They might also be *native* offsets (as one would get with a native stack trace), in practice I doubt this would make any difference (the issue with large native offsets indicating mismatched symbols doesn't apply to .NET).

Comment: Offsets from what? The InitView method above is not even close to being 1064 IL lines...

Comment: @Crassy: Not IL *lines*, but IL *offsets* - as in, the numbers shown on the left in ILDASM. A single instruction can take several bytes of IL.

Comment: Obviously this was the offset into the NATIVE code (see comment on original post). Thanks for your help!